# nothing happens when i click on the first item in android spinner. how do i fix that?

Tags: android, android-spinner

When I click on the first item in the spinner, or the default one, the spinner just collapses.  All other items perform desired action. How do I get the first item to fire an action?

Comment: please share your code and logcat if there is error message.

Comment: Without know what you expect it to do, we can't help you.  Post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having this problem (assuming you have implemented the `setOnItemSelectedListener()` for the `Spinner`) because `Spinner` calls the `onItemSelected()` only when you change the Selection, in other words select a new item in the `Spinner`. Hence the `Spinner` simply collapse when you select the default selection.

Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. do you have any suggestion on how to force it to perform an action?